# Change Background image of azure ad b2c in custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to Customize the user interface, Mainly background image in Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy sign in/sign up page.
Kindly suggest easy way to change background image, I am using custom policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer to [Customize the user interface of your application using a custom policy in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization).

To change the background image, you need to modify the code of the [HTML5 content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#create-your-html5-content).

Like this: `<body background="{the url of your image}">`.

Comment: Thanks ,its working.Can you tell me how to align the text  content here.

Comment: @RohitChouhan  Add a <p> in <body>. For example `<p style="text-align:center;">your content</p>`.